# Use multiple datasources for the same datagridview

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, binding, datasource

I have a form which contains two buttons representing families, a copy-Button, a Paste-Button and a datagridview.
The datagridView receives an object list of family memebers as datasource by clicking a Family-button.
My problem is this:
After copying and pasting data from a familiy to another family, if I edit a cell from the datagridview of a family, the changes are automatically applied to the same object of the another family. I dont understand why and what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
private void BtnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Familymember> selectedFamilyMemberList = ((BindingList<Familymember>)dgvFamilyMember.DataSource).ToList();

        if (selectedFamilyMemberList != null && selectedFamilyMemberList .Count > 0)
        {
            CopiedFamilyMemberList.AddRange(selectedFamilyMemberList);
            btnPaste.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

private void BtnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ID_FamilyPasteTo = seletedFamily.ID;

        Family[FamilyList.Find(x => x.ID == ID_FamilyPasteTo)].Clear();

        if (CopiedFamilyMemberList.Count > 0 && ID_FamilyCopyFrom != ID_FamilyPasteTo )
        {
            Family[seletedFamily].AddRange(CopiedFamilyMemberList);

            dgvDosingPart.DataSource = null;
            dgvDosingPart.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            dgvDosingPart.DataSource = new BindingList<FamilyMember>(Family[seletedFamily]);

            dgvDosingPart.Refresh();

            btnPaste.Enabled = false;
        }

        CopiedFamilyMemberList.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the `Family` declaration?

Comment: `private Dictionary<FamilyDescription, List<FamilyMember>> Family = new Dictionary<Family, List<FamilyMember>>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for this tip. It helped me to solve the problem.
I just made the class FamilyMember clonable, added the method Clone() to it and have implemented the event BtnCopy_Click again.

```
 public class FamilyMember: ICloneable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        return (FamilyMember) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

private void BtnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Familymember> selectedFamilyMemberList = ((BindingList<Familymember>)dgvFamilyMember.DataSource).ToList();

    if (selectedFamilyMemberList != null && selectedFamilyMemberList .Count > 0)
    {

        foreach (FamilyMember item in selectedFamilyMemberList)
        {
            CopiedFamilyMemberList.Add((FamilyMember)item.Clone());
        }

        btnPaste.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to create a new list:

```
List<Familymember> selectedFamilyMemberList = new List<Familymember>(((BindingList<Familymember>)dgvFamilyMember.DataSource).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are just copy the reference not the value. You have to clone the object to the other List. The easiest solution i use is to serialize/deserialize it to json or XML and have a completly new object with new reference in the List.

```
public T Clone(T obj)
{
 JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings {
  ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
  Formatting = Formatting.Indented
 };

 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, jss);
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

When you put your cloned object to the List and edit it, you should edit this object and not the one in the source list.